# Tensorflow demo implementation in android things "Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided"

Tags: android, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, android-things

I've been trying to implement the tensorflow-demo detector activity in android things but the black screen just appears. here are some code in camera connection fragment

```
private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
      final SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
      assert texture != null;

      // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
      texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight());

      // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
      final Surface surface = new Surface(texture);

      // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
      previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
      previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

      LOGGER.i("Opening camera preview: " + previewSize.getWidth() + "x" + previewSize.getHeight());

      // Create the reader for the preview frames.
      previewReader =
          ImageReader.newInstance(
              previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);

      previewReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageListener, backgroundHandler);
      previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewReader.getSurface());

      // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.

     /* cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
              Arrays.asList(surface),
              new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {*/
      cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
          Arrays.asList(surface, previewReader.getSurface()),
          new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
              // The camera is already closed
              if (null == cameraDevice) {
                return;
              }

              // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
              captureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
              try {
                // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                previewRequestBuilder.set(
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                previewRequestBuilder.set(
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);

                // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build();
                captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                    previewRequest, captureCallback, backgroundHandler);
              } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
                LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(final CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
              showToast("Failed");
            }
          },
          null);
    } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
      LOGGER.e(e, "Exception!");
    } }
```

and here is the logcat of it

```
2019-04-24 13:55:00.735 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Checking to see if TensorFlow native methods are already loaded
2019-04-24 13:55:00.736 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo E/zygote: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.contrib.android.RunStats.allocate() (tried Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate and Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate__)
2019-04-24 13:55:00.736 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: TensorFlow native methods not found, attempting to load via tensorflow_inference
2019-04-24 13:55:01.132 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded TensorFlow native methods (RunStats error may be ignored)
2019-04-24 13:55:04.607 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Model load took 1718ms, TensorFlow version: 1.13.1
2019-04-24 13:55:04.614 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded model from 'file:///android_asset/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
2019-04-24 13:55:04.618 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Camera orientation relative to screen canvas: -270
2019-04-24 13:55:04.619 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Initializing at size 640x480
2019-04-24 13:55:04.669 5046-5046/org.tensorflow.demo W/tensorflow: ImageUtils: Native library not found, native RGB -> YUV conversion may be unavailable.
2019-04-24 13:55:04.698 5046-5091/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Opening camera preview: 640x480
2019-04-24 13:55:04.830 5046-5091/org.tensorflow.demo W/CameraDevice-JV-0: Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:372: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
2019-04-24 13:55:04.854 5046-5091/org.tensorflow.demo E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
2019-04-24 13:55:05.895 5046-5094/org.tensorflow.demo D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
```

when i run the same code in mobile device, it shows a camera preview. here is the logcat

```
22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Checking to see if TensorFlow native methods are already loaded
    2019-04-24 15:04:09.397 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo E/zygote64: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.contrib.android.RunStats.allocate() (tried Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate and Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate__)
    2019-04-24 15:04:09.397 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: TensorFlow native methods not found, attempting to load via tensorflow_inference
    2019-04-24 15:04:09.468 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded TensorFlow native methods (RunStats error may be ignored)
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.838 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Model load took 984ms, TensorFlow version: 1.13.1
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.841 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded model from 'file:///android_asset/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.844 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Camera orientation relative to screen canvas: 90
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.846 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Initializing at size 640x480
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.875 22508-22520/org.tensorflow.demo I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=21KB
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.877 22508-22520/org.tensorflow.demo I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=18KB
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.877 22508-22520/org.tensorflow.demo I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.882 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo W/tensorflow: ImageUtils: Native library not found, native RGB -> YUV conversion may be unavailable.
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.936 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/PermissionManager: camera remind result:true
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.936 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/CameraManager: open camera: 0, package name: org.tensorflow.demo
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.936 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/HwSystemManager: pkgName = org.tensorflow.demo pid = 22508uidOf3RdApk = 10158permType = 0permCfg=1
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.937 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/BackgroundPermManager: pkgName: org.tensorflow.demo,pid: 22508 ,uidOf3RdApk: 10158 ,permType: 0 ,permCfg: 1
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.943 22508-22529/org.tensorflow.demo I/CameraManagerGlobal: single back camera, do not need hide aux camera, device number: 2
    2019-04-24 15:04:10.943 22508-22529/org.tensorflow.demo I/CameraManagerGlobal: single back camera, do not need hide aux camera, device number: 2
    2019-04-24 15:04:11.003 22508-22540/org.tensorflow.demo I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Opening camera preview: 640x480
    2019-04-24 15:04:11.008 22508-22540/org.tensorflow.demo E/BufferQueueProducer: [] Can not get hwsched service
    2019-04-24 15:04:11.130 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 5
    2019-04-24 15:04:11.132 22508-22508/org.tensorflow.demo I/Choreographer: Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    2019-04-24 15:04:11.429 22508-22540/org.tensorflow.demo D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Initializing buffer 0 at size 307200
    2019-04-24 15:04:11.431 22508-22540/org.tensorflow.demo D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Initializing buffer 1 at size 153599
    2019-04-24 15:04:11.434 22508-22540/org.tensorflow.demo D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: Initializing buffer 2 at size 153599
```

I assume that there is no problem with the preview size since from both of the result in logcat, it opens with the same camera preview size with 640 x 480